# JS - Drag&drop files and get file type fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get the file type of pasted data, but an ERROR is thrown in the console:

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sZjNq/3/)

**Error:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
```

**JS:**

```
var reader = new FileReader();

$(".paste").on('drop', function( e ) {

    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    var file = e.target.files || (e.dataTransfer && e.dataTransfer.files);

    var legalTypes = ["image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/gif"];

    if(legalTypes.indexOf(file.type) === -1) {

        alert("Please only upload image files!");
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: You don't have any file type inputs.

Comment: This is what you want to achieve [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sZjNq/4/)

Comment: @RahilWazir I don't understand, I thought the file input is the pasted file

Answer (score 0):

use `event.originalEvent` to get `dataTransfer` object.

Also the files object will contain array of files. so you need to loop through them or use first element.

the final code will be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   var reader = new FileReader();

$(".paste").on('drop', function( e ) {

    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    var files = e.originalEvent.target.files || (e.originalEvent.dataTransfer && e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files);

    var legalTypes = ["image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/gif"];

    for( i in files ) {

        if(legalTypes.indexOf(files[i].type) < 0 ) {

            alert("Please only upload image files!");
            return false;
        }
    }

    });

   });
```